# Cannot get id of BottomNavigationView

Tags: java, android, bottomnavigationview

I'm setting up a bottom navigation for my app. I want to set/customize the actions for the menus but I'm facing an issue in the code. It can not find the id 'bottomNavView_bar' of the bottomnavigationview. I'm getting the error "Can't resolve symbol 'bottomNavView_bar'"

Here is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<!--parent relative layout-->
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/parent_relative_layout">

    <!--top bar layout-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/relLayoutTopbar">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tabs">

            </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!--middle layout-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/relLayoutMiddle"
        android:layout_below="@id/relLayoutTopbar"
        android:background="@color/mainbackgroud">

        <!--view pager-->
        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/homecontainer">

        </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!--bottom bar layout-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/relLayoutBottombar"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">


<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavView_bar"
            app:itemBackground="@color/bgBottomNavigation"
            android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
            app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu">

        </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here's the menu file bottom_navigation_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_shop"
    android:icon="@drawable/news"
    android:title="@string/title_home" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_games"
    android:icon="@drawable/hockeystick"
    android:title="@string/title_games" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_stats"
    android:icon="@drawable/graphic"
    android:title="@string/title_stats" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/settings"
    android:title="@string/title_settings" />
</menu>
```

here is part of my MainActivity.java

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new 
SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.homecontainer);
    setupViewPager(mViewPager);

    TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_rss_feed);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_alarm);

    //bottom navigation bar

    BottomNavigationView navigation = 
(BottomNavigationView)findViewById(R.id.bottomNavView_bar); //trying to get the view id here
BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(navigation);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Select tools>-android>-SDK manager

and download the SDK build tools, SDK platform and Google API's( the Google API stores packages such as "import android.view.Menu" etc.) for the target SDK version of your project(20 as shown in your screenshot). if you are not sure which items you have to download, you can select all of them. (will take more time to download of course).

Restart the IDE